# wso2 enteprise intergrator (app server trigger dss api)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Since WSO2 EI combined database service server and application server in single platform but when I trigger DSS API from the .car application deployed in EI, i was below getting error

*FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: {http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice}getXXX
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
FINEST|4000/1|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|17-05-02 03:08:03|  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*

The code is previously working fine if deploy in seperate wso2 application server and wso2 database service server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you trigger dss throw call or send message to wsdl endpoint?

It's may be problem that endpoint try initialize before dss service ready when you deploy your car. You can try to edit your endpoint and check your trigger again. It's may be correct by use address endpoint for example instead wsdl.

Comment: i had tested to trigger dss service alone and manage to get return result.

Comment: I meant that problem may be not in dss but in endpoint of it. Do you use endpoint and do you try to resave it by hands?

Comment: Yes. And i tried to trigger another separate dss server (non EI) service, i managed to see there is request and response in soap tracer in the separate dss.